When would we use “真够”
I come across this word in HSK-4 book
’你来得真够准时的‘

and this seems a bit strange to me as i understand that 真 is enough to emphasize the person is punctual. What does 够 do in this sentence and does 挺够 or 很够 acceptable?

In your example sentence, 你来得真够准时的, the meaning is not just that the person is punctual, but that they arrived exactly on time/just barely before the deadline. For example, if the meeting is at 9:30 and they arrived at 9:29:50 you could say this to them.
够 in the sentence is there meaning to reach a certain point/threshold and is to emphasize they arrived precisely to the second. It would be hard to arrive any later and still be considered on-time.
Note that if you write the sentence with just 真， it should be 你来的真准时。By adding in 够。。的，we emphasize 准时 to the most extreme case.
Both 挺够 and 很够 are not grammatically correct and should not be used.

in english we actually have an equivalent phrase, "arrived at 9 on the dot" emphasizing its not early or on time or late, but exact.

One meaning of 够 is "及". The sentence "你来得真够准时的" really means "你来得真及时啊".
真够 = 确实/的确够
挺够 = 很够 = 非常够

真够啊是什么意思？
What does 真够啊 mean?
“真够啊” 是近年来流行的网络用语，
“真够啊” is a fashionable internet phrase in recent years,
常常用于表达惊讶、不满或无奈的情绪。
often used to express a certain sense of astonishment, dissatisfaction or frustration.
它的意思十分简单明了，
The meaning is very clear and simple,
直白表达了对某件事情的不满或惊讶，
frankly expressing dissatisfaction or amazement towards something,
而且语气中带有一份无奈和苦涩。
furthermore the tone carries a sense of helplessness, even agony.
"真够"的用法
嗬，真够辣的！
Wow, (this is) really spicy!
我可真够傻的。
I am such a fool!
我累了。这一天可真够长的。
I'm shagged. It's been a freakin' long day!
